# vb Regex Parsing

Tags: regex, vb.net

EDIT: Not sure why but stack is inserting a huge space in between "div" and "class".

Regex 1:

```
<div class="mt">
GET TEXT HERE
<div class="bubble-arrow"></div>
```

my attmept:

```
Dim M As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\s*<div class=""mt"">.*<div class=""bubble-arrow""></div>")
```

Regex 1 Note: this actually works if everything is on 1 row/without line 2 or 3.

Regex 2:

```
<label>Bo:</label>
<div class="value" title="GETLINE1TEXT
GETLINE2TEXT
GETLINE3TEXT">
```

my attempt:

```
Dim B As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\s*<label>Bo:</label>\s*<div class=""value"" title="".*"">")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry for my fail to properly post threads, my problem is that I cannot parse the code where the ".*" is located. Im trying to grab the data that is between ""mt""> and <div and on the other regex between title"" and "">. In shorter words grab text on multiple lines the first regex grabs the text if its on a single row.